# Search String With Regex? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below:
"No reservation is available to allocate within the group StorageGroup1.     Total 330 GB of storage was requested"

What sometimes however I don't always get that exact string (with the group and the Total GB number being a variable) but when I do get that exact string grouping I know I can route that ticket to the appropriate group.  Whats the best way to parse it and then pull out the storage group and the number so when I create the ticket it can be dynamic

Comment: *with the group and the Total GB number being a variable* - if they are variables - why need to parse them?

Comment: because its a generic error handler so I know when I get that specific message it routes one way and different error massages can route another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = "No reservation is available to allocate within the group StorageGroup1. Total 330 GB of storage was requested";
var myRegexp = /No reservation is available to allocate within the group StorageGroup(\d). Total (.*) of storage was requested/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
if (match != null) {
  var storageGroup = match[1];
  var size = match[2];
}
```

you can trim myRegexp depending on your needs, I just put the whole sentences in it to be on the safe side.
http://jsfiddle.net/xbvpsp19/

UPDATE after @krispykream4's comment:
If group name may change, following can be used:

```
var myString = "No reservation is available to allocate within the group StorageGroup1. Total 330 GB of storage was requested";
var myRegexp = /No reservation is available to allocate within the group (\w*)(\d). Total (.*) of storage was requested/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
if (match != null) {
  var storageGroup = match[1];
  var groupName = match[2];
  var size = match[3];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LhL0w232

Comment: Thanks my guess is that (\d) is pulling out the StorageGroup number but what if the group was named something else like "AutomationGroup" or something else like x

Answer (score 0):

It will go with something like:

```
var text = "No reservation is available to 
  allocate within the group StorageGroup1. Total 330 GB of storage was requested";

var result = text.match(/\d+\sGB/)[0];
```

**/\d+\sGB/** means:

**\d+** are the numbers followed by **\s** space followed by the size expressed with to letters **GB**

Comment: "pull out the storage group" make sure to capture that group as well.